# Loading a json data file in javascript and avoiding caching

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

How can I load a JSON file inside of my javascript file, and make sure that if I update the JSON file when users view my website it will always use the latest version and not used a cached version?

Say in my javascript I load a file that is a JSON data file like this:

```
 // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at
        // http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp
        script.src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/json/earthquake_GeoJSONP.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

If the remote file changes, how can I ensure it always loads the latest version of the file and is not cached by the browser?

Comment: Do you control the server which hosts the javascript file?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the »If modified since« header in a XHR. Basically you request the same file, but with the `if-modified-since: <some date from the past>` header added. If the file has changed, you get a `200` Status plus the content, otherwise a `304` status code in the header an no content. But the server must support that, but in this case (google api), I guess that should work.

[source](https://varvy.com/ifmodified.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can insert the actual timestamp for src
script.src += '?v=' + Date.now();

Comment: What if the contents are not changed, and the cached copy can be used?